# How to debug databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to data-binding and I am having a hard-time setting it up for my WPF application:

I have a class Test which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and a property Text.

When I do this in the code-behind:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Text");
b.Source = Test;
label1.SetBinding(ContentProperty, b);
```

everything works great.

When I do the same thing in XAML:

```
Content="{Binding Source=Window.Test, Path=Text}"
```

The label content does not update.

I would like to avoid having to do this in the code-behind, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look in your Output Window, there will be an exception that tells you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to give a name to the Window in XAML (e.g. `root`) and use `ElementName` to define the binding source:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Test.Text}"
```

Comment: Solved my problem. One thing, when I try to use the Properties Window to set the Content, I select ElementName to root but Test does not appear in the choice list, so I have to enter the code manually. Is there any way to make it appear, or is this impossible for this situation?

Comment: @user472875, the designer sees that `root` is of type `Window`, so it looks for properties declared in the `Window` class, not properties declared in your specific window...

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, set the window DataContext to your `Test` instance:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Test
            {
                Text = "Hello, World!"
            };
    }
}
```

Then declare databinding in XAML:

```
Content="{Binding Path=Text}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> what am I doing wrong?

You are making unfounded assumptions about how something *ought* to work about which you do not have much of a clue. You are dealing with two fundamentally different languages here and just because you *want* WPF to interpret `Window.Test` as a reference to some specific window you had in mind does not make it so.

XAML is fundamentally string-based, for the most part strings are converted to primitive types like ints and doubles, e.g. when you set the height of a control you pass a `string` to a property of type `double`. The XAML parser knows via reflection that the property is of type `double` and tries to convert the `string` (using a default [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047.aspx) if no other has been specified). Now what do you think happens if a property is of type `object`? What is the parser to do? Well, it is not going to do anything as a `string` is *already* an `object`.

Guess what type [`Binding.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) has and what the source object of your binding will be when you write `Window.Test`...